# Query error - file is encrypted or is not a database

Tags: sql, sqlite, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I set up a ColdFusion 10 "Other" Database Source to connect to SQLite Database.

```
CF DSN: Spiceworks
JDBC URL: jdbc:sqlite:\\spiceworks\C$\Program Files\Spiceworks\db\spiceworks_prod.db
Driver Name:  sqlitejdbc-v056.jar
User name: <username>
Password: <password>

Status is OK.
```

I am receiving the following error.

```
Error Executing Database Query.   
file is encrypted or is not a database   

The error occurred in C:/Inetpub/wwwroot/intra/SmartTV/UnassignedTickets/Tickets.cfm: line 204

202 :     <cfset obj = createObject("java", "org.sqlite.JDBC")>
203 : 
204 :     <cfquery name="qry" datasource="Spiceworks">
205 :     SELECT
206 :     id,

SQL    SELECT id, summary, status, created_at, assigned_to 
FROM tickets WHERE status = 'open'  AND assigned_to IS NULL 
ORDER BY created_at DESC  

DATASOURCE   Spiceworks 

Resources: 
•Check the ColdFusion documentation to verify that you are using the correct syntax.
•Search the Knowledge Base to find a solution to your problem.

Browser   Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko 
Remote Address   10.35.102.172 
Referrer    
Date/Time   11-Jun-14 02:20 PM
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
Stack Trace  
at cfTickets2ecfm1617356019.runPage(C:/Inetpub/wwwroot/intra/SmartTV/UnassignedTickets/Tickets.cfm:204) 
at cfTickets2ecfm1617356019.runPage(C:/Inetpub/wwwroot/intra/SmartTV/UnassignedTickets/Tickets.cfm:204) 

java.sql.SQLException: file is encrypted or is not a database
at org.sqlite.DB.throwex(DB.java:288)
at org.sqlite.NativeDB.prepare(Native Method)
at org.sqlite.DB.prepare(DB.java:114)
at org.sqlite.Stmt.execute(Stmt.java:82)
at coldfusion.server.j2ee.sql.JRunStatement.execute(JRunStatement.java:265)
at coldfusion.sql.Executive.executeQuery(Executive.java:1452)
at coldfusion.sql.Executive.executeQuery(Executive.java:1201)
at coldfusion.sql.Executive.executeQuery(Executive.java:1131)
at coldfusion.sql.SqlImpl.execute(SqlImpl.java:406)
at coldfusion.tagext.sql.QueryTag.executeQuery(QueryTag.java:1056)
at coldfusion.tagext.sql.QueryTag.doEndTag(QueryTag.java:685)
at cfTickets2ecfm1617356019.runPage(C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\intra\SmartTV\UnassignedTickets\Tickets.cfm:204)
at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:244)
at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:444)
at coldfusion.filter.CfincludeFilter.invoke(CfincludeFilter.java:65)
at coldfusion.filter.IpFilter.invoke(IpFilter.java:64)
at coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter.invoke(ApplicationFilter.java:428)
at coldfusion.filter.RequestMonitorFilter.invoke(RequestMonitorFilter.java:48)
at coldfusion.filter.MonitoringFilter.invoke(MonitoringFilter.java:40)
at coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java:112)
at coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:94)
at coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28)
at coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38)
at coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(NoCacheFilter.java:46)
at coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38)
at coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22)
at coldfusion.filter.CachingFilter.invoke(CachingFilter.java:62)
at coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java:219)
at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42)
at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:928)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:414)
at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:204)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process`enter code here`(AbstractProtocol.java:539)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:298)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

In my Data Source, I am attempting to connect to a database on a different server "spiceworks". I think that is the issue. Has anyone successfully been able to create a SQLite datasource that points to a db on a different server? Should I add a "Connection String" under "Show Advanced Settings" of the Data source properties? IF so, what should it be like?

Comment: Does the account ColdFusion use have permissions to access that file? By default it won't.

Comment: I do not know if sqlite/driver even supports remote connections ... As a test, copy the database locally. Then update the DSN to use the local path. If it works locally, points to a possible permissions problem as mentioned, or maybe it is just not supported.

Comment: @AdamCameron How do I give the ColdFusion account permissions to access the file that is on a different server?

Comment: That's kinda outside the scope of this question, but the answer is "the same way you'd do so for any user". You're probably gonna have to use a domain user or something, but if you don't know how to set user perms (which is entirely reasonable), then you need to ask the appropriate question on the appropriate forum (probably serverfault.com?)